# Using a select drop down list more than once

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I am looking for a way to use some drop down lists more than once in a website (sometimes it will be more than once on the same page, others from a different page). This is in HTML 5, with javascript. Any suggestions on where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want a model-view pattern that separate the rendering (view, in your case the select element) from the data (model, in your case the list of options).

You could start by looking at popular libraries like Ember or Angular.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would be a good start. You can easily clone and paste DOM elements with jQuery. If you can't use jQuery I would suggest checking out [the cloneNode method.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)